# Make a repeater linkbutton hidden with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater, hidden

I have a repeater and some items in it. One of these items is a linkbutton. I want to hide it and actually I can but only the first one. I mean if repeater displays 4 records, only the first one's linkbutton becomes hidden. I can see that I need a loop to turn inside the repeater and hide all linkbuttons but I really stuck since I am beginner in javascript. 
Here is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceHdcvi" ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        //Some other code
        <div id="silBeni" class="sil fl">
          <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteProduct" runat="server" Text="Kaldır" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UrunId")%>' CommandName="deleteProduct" OnClick="LinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And my javascript code:

```
function hideColumn() {
    sartnameDiv.style.display = 'block';

    var bizimDiv = document.getElementById("silBeni");
    bizimDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this hideCoulmn method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to search by class. There cannot be several elements with the same id, so instead we search several elements by class.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sil");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  element.style.display = "none";
});
```

Note that ordinary array functions cannot be used on the result from getElementsByClassName, so that is why you need the

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call
```

instead of just writing like for an ordinary array.

```
elements.forEach(function(element){
});
```

Do note however, that now we will find all elements that have the class sil, meaning that if you have more elements with this class on the page, they will also be found, so you may have to adjust your html accordingly.

Edit: as per  Webruster's comment, we also need to make sure that the function gets called when we want it to get called.

Comment: @fakenick, i just added some more point that instead of changing HTMl we can create a CSS and append to the element where you want to hide them so that code changing would be minimised .

Comment: @Webruster yes, separating behavior from style is usually good. If we get into classes, then another option would be to use some kind of hide class, like .hide { display:none } and add that instead, manipulating style on element level with element.style.display makes me feel a bit uneasy.

Comment: @Fakenick +1 for explaining the use of  `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the HTML, you can create a dummy css and append to the HTML for which you want to do some operation and the rest opteration is cleanly explained by @Fakenick .
 Please see how you can add that dummy css below :

Here is the **HTMl**

```
<asp:Repeater DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceHdcvi" ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        //Some other code
        <div id="silBeni" class="sil fl hideclass">
          <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteProduct" runat="server" Text="Kaldır" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UrunId")%>' CommandName="deleteProduct" OnClick="LinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Make a dummy **Css** and try to append to the **Div** that to be hidden

```
<style>
.hideclass{
}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
function hideColumn() {
    sartnameDiv.style.display = 'block';
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hideclass");
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  element.style.display = "none";
});

}
```